# SHA1, SHA256 or MD5 hash of Windows 7 SP1 installation ISO

Tags: windows, windows-7, installation, iso-image, hashing

I know that Windows 7 is end-of-life, but for software testing and other reasons, I need to reinstall a Windows 7 from the original ISO.

I'm specifically looking for *"Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit with SP1"* ISO.

I have already read [Where can I download Windows 7 (legally from Microsoft)?](https://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-can-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft) but answers there are either deprecated, or give access to a download link but from a *non-official* source, which I don't want.
Since I won't probably find a `WIN7_64_ULTIMATE_SP1.iso` on an official Microsoft website anymore, here is the last solution:

**Is there an official Microsoft website (`microsoft.com` or `digitalrivercontent.net` or another one) displaying the SHA1, SHA256 or MD5 of such a Win7 SP1 ISO?**

Once I'll have this hash, I will be able to download the ISO from anywhere (including possibly untrusted websites), and double-check it's the genuine ISO.

Note: this is not a duplicate of [Where can I download Windows 7 (legally from Microsoft)?](https://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-can-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft)
Also, this post is *not* seeking product recommendations, thus it is *not* off topic, it is on topic, similarly to [Where can I download Windows 7 (legally from Microsoft)?](https://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-can-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft).

Comment: I have posted this: https://superuser.com/a/1718341/221041 but it would be even better if we could find an official Microsoft or Digitalrivercontent page (on archive.org maybe) which give the SHA1 of the official ISO.

Comment: My answer the last time I checked it, which requires a retail Windows 7 license key, still works has something changed.  That particular solution is directly from Microsoft.  Honestly, all the non-deleted answers are actually directly from Microsoft but that’s beside the point. Content on Digital River isn’t accessible, so you can request those links, but they no longer exist